# Accessing an object within an unindexed Array of Structure

Tags: c#, arrays, structure

I have an array of structure objects initialized like below:

```
struct1 SettingList[] = { {"as","bs","cs"} , {"ak","bk",ck"} }
```

struct1 is defined as follows:

```
struct1{char[] str1; char[] str2; char[] str3}
```

I was translating some C++ code to C# and in the c++ code I saw an object accessed like below:

```
SettingList["as"].str1
```

How can you access an object with the first member of that object? How would I do that in c# without having to specify SettingList[0].str1

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary instead of a `map`.

```
var settingsList = yourArray.ToDictionary(i => i[0]);
var foo = settingsList["as"];
```

Comment: I assume you mean array, not "map".

Comment: @Servy no i do mean a dictionary per " was translating some C++ code to C# and in the c++ code I saw an object accessed like below:"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the struct that has the given string as the first of the values you can use this:

```
var value = SettingList.First(setting => setting[0] == "as").str1;
```

If you want to use the `[]` operator to do this then you'll need to create your own type that holds onto such an array and that does something like the above in the overloaded `[]` operator implementation.

Comment: Or use `KeyedCollection<TKey, TValue>`